# array formula with dates

Tags: arrays, date, formula

I have four columns of dates(A,B,C,D),I want to excel verify if each period of "period 2" intersects ALL "period 1" from 1,2,3.....

For example `20-28/01/2016` intersects `01-24/01/2016` AND 2`5/01-03/02/2016`. The answer in this case in column E must be "wrong".

I think this have to be an array because in a cell must be verified an entire column. If it could be done without array I would be very happy, because array slow time calculation very much down on my computer .

```
_________________________________________________________________
         |    A     |    B     |    C     |    D     |     E     |
         |       period 1      |       period 2      |           |
1        |01/01/2016|24/01/2016|20/01/2016|28/01/2016|  "wrong"  |
2        |25/01/2016|03/02/2016|04/02/2016|10/02/2016|  "ok"     |
3        |
```

Comment: if not a duplicate, at least related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: sorry, I didn't mentioned that I want this by formula, not by VBA.